# Find non-integer values in a float field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble finding a way to write a query that will return all non-integers in a float column in SQL Server 2005/8.

I have a float field where the majority of the data in it is actually integers, but I'd like to take a look at the rows where the values actually contain a decimal value. The first thing I tried was modulus 1, but the % operator doesn't work on float values.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Lots of great answers using interesting and different approaches. I wish I could choose more than one accepted answer! Upvotes for everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

are you just wanting the rows with a decimal in it?

```
select field
from table
where field like '%.%'
```

Comment: It actually works as-is in my case.  Great trick, wish I'd thought of it.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know exact syntax of MSSQL, however you could try something like that (pseudo-code)

```
SELECT ... FROM tbl_name WHERE col_name != CAST(col_name AS INTEGER)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE (CONVERT(INT, floatField) - floatField) <> 0
```

Comment: This could be simplified to `SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE CONVERT(INT, floatField) <> floatField`. Same as Crozin's answer :P

Comment: @P5Coder - I'm not entirely sure that this does exactly the same thing due to the way SQL server will coerce the variables to the same types.  Would need to really dig into it to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

You may also try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col != ROUND(col)
```

Comment: I couldn't actually get this to work, tsql round requires 2-3 arguments [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx), and no matter what value I supply it returns 'wonky' results. Thanks for your input though. :)